# Fill data in multiple textfields from a list containing multiple dictionaries in C# (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a List which has 16 Dictionary items, I want to assign the values of this 16 dictionaries into 16 different text fields. What I am doing now is this

```
txtAccountType.Text = SheetData[0]["KeyName"].ToString();
txtAccountName.Text = SheetData[1]["KeyName"].ToString();
txtAccountAddress.Text = SheetData[2]["KeyName"].ToString();
txtAccountActivationDate.Text = SheetData[3]["KeyName"].ToString();
txtAccountExpiry.Text = SheetData[4]["KeyName"].ToString();
```

> SheetData is a instance of List class containing multiple dictionaries.

I thought of using the for loop as well but the problem is that it did not work because every time I used to see the last dictionaries value in all the text fields.

The above solution works fine for me but what if I get 15 dictionaries or 10 dictionaries in future, the solution I am using is not dynamic here so could you please suggest me on how can I improve this.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to decide which data to assign for particular textbox. If any data can be assigned to any of the text box below code will work for you. It works like first element will be assigned to first textbox.

```
int i = 0;
    foreach (Control ctl in controls)
    {
        if (ctl is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox txt = (TextBox)ctl;
            txt.Text = SheetData[i]["KeyName"].ToString();

            i++;
        }
    }
```

Here controls are the collection of `ControlCollection` object. For example you can collect it from form like this  `ControlCollection controls = this.form1.Controls;`